# Restoring image of Time Machine disk

Tags: time-machine

I have a raw image of a Time Machine disk made with ddrescue, now I'd like to know if I can hook it up on the Mac and restore data from it.

Comment: Time machine disks are in HFS+ Linux doe snot really support that. I think you need to explain more e.g. is the disk attached via network - what was the Linix command you used

Comment: ddrescue is a bit-bit copy tool, it does not look on filesystems. With hfsprogs and other stuff like that on my debian by default, I had zero problem on reading files and folders on the drive

Comment: You can certainly take a Tim machine drive to any Mac and see if it’s readable. Finder will show you all the files that time machine would offer to restore in a folder based structure.

Comment: I just want to know if there's a way to hook a raw image on timemachine without too much effort, I already managed to mount the raw image on debian and with tmfs I mounted it without problems, I don't want to know about the linux part, I just want to know what to do on the new iMac on which i'd like to restore the data from the raw image

Comment: @bmike not in this case, I managed to look on it from a linux system but on different macs I had problems, it would just spin the disks without recognizing anything

Comment: @GodTaxist Is it a raw image of a Time Machine volume (e.g. sdc2) or the whole disk (e.g. sdc)?

Comment: I guess is you have a [sparse bundle](https://superuser.com/questions/306497/) or [plain hfs+](https://superuser.com/questions/84446/) you wouldn’t even need Mac to read, no? Just copy out what you need without getting Time Machine to see your image as valid.

Comment: @klanomath I have both, thus it should need just a fdisk -l and a mount with offset to get the partition from the whole disk image

Comment: @bmike, **I've already did that, as I wrote before**. I want to know if it can be mounted on mac without much problems and, more important, if it can be hooked on timemachine without problems to restore everything with the migration assistant. I just want to know the *mac* part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to mount the dd image.

- Transfer the file to your Mac, add .dmg as file extension and open the file

or

- Transfer the file to your Mac, attach and mount it with hdiutil:

  ```
  hdiutil attach -imagekey diskimage-class=CRawDiskImage -nomount ~/path/to/file
  ```

  and with the printed device identifier:

  ```
  hdiutil mount /dev/diskXsY
  ```

Then check with `tmutil destinationinfo` if the now mounted backup volume is associated with the Mac. If a reassociation is necessary check the inheritbackup and associatedisk verbs in `man tmutil`.